# Typescript build getting errors from node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, npm, gulp, tsc, gulp-typescript

I am running a typescript build and getting errors in node_modules.  Why isn't it ignoring this folder?  I have it in the exclude section of my tsconfig.json.  The really strange thing is that I have another project that I have done a file comparison with and it does not throw these errors even though gulpfile.js, tsconfig.json and the node_modules folders are identical.  What else can I check?

Errors:

```
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(4,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(14,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(24,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.d.ts(25,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,103): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.d.ts(436,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(13,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(14,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(95,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(96,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/collection.d.ts(97,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(14,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.d.ts(78,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(3,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/http/headers.d.ts(43,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/http/url_search_params.d.ts(11,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(75,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(85,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(22,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(72,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(77,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(77,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(65,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(65,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(72,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(77,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(100,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(154,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(159,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
c:/Dev/streak-maker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(159,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages"
  ]
}
```

gulpfile.js (I am running the build-typescript task - I get the same errors when just typing tsc at the command line)

```
/// <binding Build='default' />

var del = require('del'),
    gulp = require("gulp"),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

var webproj = "./src/StreakMaker.Web/";
var webroot = webproj + "wwwroot/";
var appsource = webproj + "App/";
var appout = webroot + "app/";
var jspmsource = "./jspm_packages/";
var jspmout = webroot + "jspm_packages/";

var paths = {
    webroot: webroot,
    src: appsource,
    app: appout,
    jspm: jspmsource,
    jspm_out: jspmout
};

gulp.task('watch', ['watch-typescript', 'watch-html']);

gulp.task('watch-typescript', function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.src + '/**/*.ts', ['build-typescript']);
});

gulp.task('clean-typescript', function () {
    del([paths.app + '/**/*.ts']);
});

gulp.task('build-typescript', ['clean-typescript'], function () {
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('./tsconfig.json');

    gulp.src(paths.src + '/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts(tsProject))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app));
});

gulp.task('watch-html', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.src + '/**/*.html', ['copy-html']);
});

gulp.task('clean-html', function () {
    del([paths.app + '/**/*.html']);
});

gulp.task('copy-html', ['clean-html'], function () {
    gulp.src(paths.src + '/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.app));
});

gulp.task('copy-jspm', ['clean-jspm', 'copy-config'], function() {
    gulp.src(paths.jspm + "**/*.{js,css,map}")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jspm_out));
});

gulp.task('clean-jspm', function(){
    del([paths.jspm_out + "**/*.*"]); 
});

gulp.task('copy-config', ['clean-config'], function(){
    gulp.src("./config.js")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot));
});

gulp.task('clean-config', function(){
    del(paths.webroot + 'config.js'); 
});

gulp.task('default', ['build-typescript', 'copy-html', 'copy-jspm']);
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well.

I added the following to the top of the TS file that contained the import {bootstrap} line:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

Your path may be different of course for that file.

Comment: This is very useful (+1), and if following the [quickstart on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), just referencing the top level typings directly works too: `/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />`

Comment: Has Any one found a solution ...ive tried all ways.all i get is cannot find map,set,expect ....

Comment: Well, it is considered that <reference> tag is a bad practice. Here is an [article](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/) that Minko Gechev wrote about this exact error. [Here](http://myrighttocode.org/blog/typescript/angular2/components/npm/angular2-npm-components) is another article that explains the whole packaging process.

Answer (score 23):

You can add the `skipLibCheck` property with `true` value into your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

With this property will skip the type checking into declaration files (`*.d.ts`)

[Thanks to the source](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-disable-type-checking-node-modules)

Comment: Thank you!! This was the right answer (for me anyway).
I am trying to use types for a js project, within VSCode at work - not fully wanting to opt-in to ts just yet, and this fixed my issue.

Comment: Should be top answer IMHO. It's not very obvious that exclusion of node modules is not enough to get rid out of the library-dependant compilation errors.

Answer (score 19):

If you're targeting ES5, add "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" to tsconfig.json file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "built",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "files": [
      "helloworld.ts",
      "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Newbie comment. Doing this in visual studio 2015 got me 43k new typescript build errors.

Comment: This worked for me when some modules said they couldn't find their dependencies.

Comment: With this line of code you prevent TypeScript to check types of other files.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app/main';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

works well, wenn using gulpjs I prefer however instead of populating source file with comments, an addition of typings file directly to the source of the corresponding gulpjs task, like for example:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  return gulp
    .src([
      'typings/browser.d.ts',
      tsSrc + '**/*.ts'
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(appSrc + 'js/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In RC1 demo, the shim is provided by the `core-js` module and type definitions are managed by the `typings` tool. Adding `typings/index.d.ts` to `gulp.src` should fix the issue:

```
function buildTypeScriptFn(files) {
  files = files || ['app/**/*.ts','typings/index.d.ts'];

  return function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(files)
      .pipe(changed(paths.dirs.build, { extension: '.js' }))
      .pipe(ts(tscConfig.compilerOptions));

    return merge(tsResult.dts, tsResult.js)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dirs.build));
  }
}

gulp.task('ts', buildTypeScriptFn());
```

Answer (score -3):

i had the same problem,  just try running not with "**npm start**", 
but with "**npm run lite**". Its much more convenient to use.

Comment: this worked for me. will it have any problems in the future?