# tsc not excluding node_modules

Tags: typescript, angular, tsc

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to upgrade an angular2/beta8 app to RC1, and I'm doing so by basically restructuring according to the Quickstart guide.

I copied its tsconfig.json into my project directory. I think I've got everything else ready,but when I run `tsc`, I get all kinds of errors within files in my node_modules folder. Why is it even looking in there in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382157/typescript-build-getting-errors-from-node-modules-folder

Comment: Which version of TypeScript? If it is before 1.6, then upgrade.

Comment: @paleo, `tsc -v` shows 1.8.10

Answer (score 45):

Add this option in  ***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the downsides of using this?

Comment: see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if you found an answer to this Alex but the referred to [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382157/typescript-build-getting-errors-from-node-modules-folder) in the comments by LDL provides an answer, submitted by Srikanth Injarapu.

Here's the answer just in case someone doesn't feel like going to that link:

> If you're targeting ES5, add
>   "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" to tsconfig.json file :

```
 {    
   "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "commonjs",
     "target": "es5",
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "outDir": "built",
     "rootDir": ".",
     "sourceMap": false
   },
   "files": [
     "helloworld.ts",
     "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
   ],
   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"
   ]
 }
```

**EDIT**

In my application I make use of webpack to build my app and I still get the same errors being spat out on the console. I'm currently looking in to fixing this and will report back with what I find.

Comment: Pretty sure in 2019 the solution is to add `"lib": ["es6"],` to `compilerOptions`.

Comment: No, adding `"lib": ["es6"],` didn't work for me. The original answer did, though.

Comment: for Webpack 4.43.0 you only need: ```javascript
    "files": [  
        "src/index.ts",    
        "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"  
    ]   
```
Where src/index.ts is one of my entries.

Answer (score 3):

**For anybody using webpack**, adding the "exclude" property did not work for me.

Instead adding all file extensions to the webpack "resolve" property and exclude node_modules from any "rules" objects worked:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
},
module: {
     rules: [
            {
               test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
               ]
             },
             // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
             {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
             },
           ]
```

Answer (score -1):

i have resolve this issue by npm updating global typescript packge

```
npm update -g typescript
```

then you can delete your tsconfig and create a new `tsc --init`