# Firebase-Admin package Typescript error in Cloud Functions Firestore : @types/googlemaps

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have two projects with similar Cloud Functions setup, both directly using Typescript setup (no Webpack) similar to [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/typescript-getting-started) or [this one](https://github.com/FrangSierra/firestore-cloud-functions-typescript)

One of them uses Firestore, other one doesn't. The one that does not use Firestore compiles and deploys with no error.

However the one with Firestore functions gives me this error on `tsc` compile:

```
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(33,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(37,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(54,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(787,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(798,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(811,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Node'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1135,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1136,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1137,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1138,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1139,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1140,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.
../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts(1141,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

... and goes on.
```

These are **package.json** dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.5.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
```

and content of the **tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015.promise"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? Is it related to Typescript version? (2.6) Do I need to import a `@types`?  Adding dev-dependency `@types/node` did not help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At first I thought problem was exclusion of `node_modules` folder in `tsconfig` file and removed `"exclude": [ "node_modules" ]` part. It did not help.

Then since all errors seems to be related to DOM element names or "Node", it should be about a missing types definition of some general package, hence did another search on that matter and run into this answer of a similar question: [Typescript build getting errors from node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38959037/1539073)

Changing `tsconfig` like this (adding reference to `lib.es6.d.ts`) make my problem go away:

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
```

Comment: I had been struggling with this for so long and you helped me solve it, thanks a lot!

Comment: That's work but when call `new google.maps.LatLng`it give that error during runtime `ReferenceError google is not defined`  @Bogac

Answer (score 9):

Adding 
`"skipLibCheck": true` to tsconfig.json also does the trick.

credit - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/749#issuecomment-385693352

Comment: but why though?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with Firebase functions project. **FULL solution** for:

**node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1629:8 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.**

1. Inside your project folder run this in cmd: `npm install -g npm-check-updates`
2. Inside your project folder, fo to `/functions` and run this in cmd: `ncu -u`
   Here you'll see something like this:

> ```
>  firebase-admin            ^9.2.0  →   ^9.5.0
>  firebase-functions       ^3.11.0  →  ^3.13.1
>  googleapis               ^40.0.0  →  ^67.0.0
>  typescript                ^3.8.0  →   ^4.1.5
>  firebase-functions-test   ^0.2.0  →   ^0.2.3
> ```

3. Here run in cmd: `npm install`
4. At this point, you can try to deploy again, but you could get this error:
   **node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1638:8 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2018' or later.**
5. In case you get error from prevous step then open file `functions/tsconfig.json` and update value for `target` node as it says in error text, in my case I updated to `es2018` and deploy should be run fine

p.s. Don't forget to save each change, just Ctrl+S ;)

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue:

node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1629:8 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AsyncIterable'.

For me, updating (from 3.12 to 3.13) firebase-functions helped.

Comment: Yup just update firebase-admin and firebase-functions to latest